# Ссылка на папку

Tags: html, html5

Здравствуйте.
У меня такой вопрос - как сделать ссылку на локальном сайте для перехода в нужную папку на компьютере, т.е. по клику по ссылке открывалось бы окно проводника в нужной папке? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если вам мой ответ подошел, то почему бы не поставить галочку? :D

Comment: потому что банально баллов не хватает))

Comment: имеется в виду зеленая галочка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так:

```
<a href="file:///C:/">Локальный диск C</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Связь с локальными ресурсами отключена во всех современных браузерах из-за ограничений безопасности.
Для [Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work):

> В целях безопасности приложения Mozilla блокируют ссылки на локальные
>   файлы (и каталоги) из удаленных файлов. Сюда входят ссылки на файлы на
>   вашем жестком диске, на подключенных сетевых дисках и доступные через
>   пути Uniform Naming Convention (UNC). Это предотвращает ряд неприятных
>   возможностей, в том числе:
>
> - Разрешить сайтам обнаруживать вашу операционную систему, проверяя пути установки по умолчанию
> - Предоставление сайтам уязвимостей системы (например, C: \ con \ con в Windows 95/98)
> - Разрешение сайтам определять предпочтения браузера или считывать конфиденциальные данные

для [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Internet Explorer 6 с пакетом обновления 1 (SP1) больше не позволяет просматривать локальную машину из зоны Интернета. Например, если интернет-сайт содержит ссылку на локальный файл, Internet Explorer 6 SP1 отображает пустую страницу, когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку. Предыдущие версии Windows Internet Explorer следовали за ссылкой на локальный файл.

для [Opera](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/896/) (в контексте рекомендаций по безопасности я уверен, что для этого есть более каноническая ссылка):

> В качестве меры предосторожности Opera не позволяет веб-страницам ссылаться на файлы на локальном диске пользователя